# How to enable autocomplete in hive terminal?

Tags: hadoop, hive, terminal

I was working with hadoop and hive while typing commands in terminal(linux) we can use **TAB** button for autocomplete. But when i type hadoop commands i.e. hdfs dfs -put   it can't auto-complete. Same case with hive terminal. 
I just want to know that is there is any possibility to add auto-complete in hadoop or hive terminal?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean Beeline (the Hive cli is deprecated)

No, there isn't.

You can use tools like HUE or maybe Apache Superset to get this feature